ASP.NET Web API - How to include / as part of parameter value in URL?
In ASP.NET Web API project, the route is  [Route("api/itemSoldPrice/{words}/")]. It is working fine if using path http://xxx/api/itemSoldPrice/book.
But if the URL is http://xxx/api/itemSoldPrice/1/2L, which words is 1/2L, it will throw 404 error.
Then I tried to change the URL into http://xxx/api/itemSoldPrice/1%2F2L%20/, while 1%2F2L%20 is the encodeURIComponent value of the original words. But 404 error is still there.
How to handle these kinds of special charactors in URL path? Thanks!
public class ItemSoldPriceController : BaseApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/itemSoldPrice/{words}/")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetItemSoldPriceByKeyWords([FromUri] string words)
    {
        
    }
}


The Url you've provided is incorrect and contains a space after decoding.
Decoded Url:
http://xxx/api/itemSoldPrice/1/2L /
Consider using this Url:
http://xxx/api/itemSoldPrice/1%2F2L/
Here I've removed the unnecesseray space. Source used for encoding/decoding:
website
About the handling of the special characters, replace the spaces with hyphens.
Solution:
Swap out the use of the name in the url entirely, instead opting out for an Id or Guid. If you really need to use names in your Url, then in your POST request create a DTO which takes in the name of the book and additional info, swaps out the spaces with hyphens and then converts the name with an UrlEncoder incase there are special characters. Then in your GET request call the [FromUrl] with the encoded name and find it in your DataBase.
